# Exoplayer video stop when audio is muted (encoder is flash)

Tags: android, rtmp, exoplayer

Hi I am creating an app that will broadcast live and another user can view it

I am currently using flash to push it into WOWZA and I am using exoplayer for viewing it

I am using RTMP because it's the only one supported by exoplayer which has low latency

everything works perfect however when I mute the microphone in the live side the video in exoplayer will freeze and will go to status

`STATE_BUFFERING` but it will not proceed to `STATE_READY`

and if I unmute it will go back to normal and can view it again from

`STATE_BUFFERING` to `STATE_READY`

And anyway I tried the stream to view in VLC and it does work it doesn't freeze

I tried other solution but doesn't work

my code is this

```
//initiate Player
//Create a default TrackSelector
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

//Create the player
SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.simple_player);
playerView.setPlayer(player);

RtmpDataSourceFactory rtmpDataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory();

// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(rtmpDataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(URL));

player.prepare(videoSource);

//auto start playing
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

I hope someone helps me!!!

thank you in advance